# "Disk quota exceeded" when writing to /tmp, but plenty of space (linux)

Tags: linux, parallels, inode, quota

i have a VPS.  It's managed with the notorious parallels plesk.

today i started seeing messages (via wordpress at first, but also from the command line shell), saying: "Disk quota exceeded".

```
user@machine:~$ echo aaa > /tmp/aaa
-bash: /tmp/aaa: Disk quota exceeded
```

but there's lots of space on the machine, and only 1 partition.

```
user@machine:~$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs             100G   24G   77G  24% /
```

I deleted all files from /tmp/*   but still.

I don't know anything about "vzfs", maybe maybe it's the culprit?

What could've gone wrong? and how can to fix it?

**Solution!**

(if you DON'T use Parallels Plesk, see @Adalee's answer)

See @deltik 's solution, relevant to Parallel's system, as in my case.

df -i   immediately gave a rediculous number of inodes:  18,446,744,069,620,218,961   which is insane for a wordpress website.

i further explored and found qmail's queue is full with inodes  (it full with some hacker's attemtps to use my machine to spam, and failure replies)

fixing qmail isn't relevant here, but my workaround is relevant:

1. stopped qmail's service
2. i wasn't able to download [qmhandle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qmhandle/) to the over-quota system, so i had to
3. extract and upload the script to another website,
4. delete the queue with this command:
5. perl <(wget -O - http://link.to.my/script.pl) -D

this way the script is running directly from the web (which is not a safe practice, but i had put the script there by myself), with command line options.

thanks @deltik for knowing and promptly recognizing this peculiar setup on the spot, and providing means to further diagnose !!!

Comment: Linux has user or group based disk quota allocation settings. Check them as well [5 Steps to Setup User and Group Disk Quota on UNIX / Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/)

Comment: Yes, `vzfs` (the OpenVZ "virtual" filesystem) can be the cause. I've seen many OpenVZ providers who sell impossibly cheap servers, but set impossibly stupid limits on them.

Comment: If you have a solution, even if specific, please post it as an answer. You can always accept someone else’s answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a VZFS filesystem, which means that your VPS is a Parallels Virtuozzo virtual machine.  In Virtuozzo the hosting provider can set limits on many parameters, including what allocations you get with VZFS.

### Cause: Out of Inodes (Most Common)

After years of working with hundreds of Virtuozzo VPS customers who have had the issue of being unable to create files, even though there appeared to be plenty of free space, the vast majority of them had reached their inode limit.  Run this command to see the inode allocation (`Inodes`), inodes used (`IUsed`), remaining inodes (`IFree`), and the percentage of inodes used (`IUse%`):

```
df -i
```

Having 100% inode usage happens a lot.  Common causes in my experience:

- Spam email bouncebacks
- Outbound spam emails queued
- A lot of inbound emails stored
- Some user setting their PHP session garbage collection (`session.gc_maxlifetime`) to over a hundred years
- Way too many general cache files
- Object cache enabled in the WordPress plugin W3 Total Cache
- Magento error log (a new file is generated for every error)
- Other poorly configured or poorly designed programs/scripts that make a bunch of files and forget to delete them

#### Troubleshooting

If you find that you are low or out of inodes but don't know where most of the them are, I have this Bash one-liner that searches the current directory and counts the inodes in at a folder depth of 1:

```
for i in $(find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort); do echo -e "$(find "$i" | wc -l)\t: $(readlink -f "$i")"; done | sort -nr
```

You can keep changing the current working directory starting from `/` until you find the culprit using up your inode allocation.

#### Explanation

Your VPS is on a VZFS filesystem, which is part of Parallels Virtuozzo (not OpenVZ, which is similar and based on the same technology, but OpenVZ wouldn't be using VZFS).

Due to the way Virtuozzo stores files in VZFS, inodes are often limited more so than they would be on other filesystems like ext4 or XFS.  The host tracks all these files, and it would be advantageous to the hosting provider not to let a single VPS take up hundreds of millions of inodes.  As a result, the hosting provider may set the inode limit to be low, like 1,000,000 inodes.

After years of working with hundreds of customers who exhausted their inode allocation on Virtuozzo, these "mysterious" disk quota issues don't surprise me anymore.

### Cause: Other Virtuozzo Limits

A very small percentage of the Virtuozzo VPS customers I've worked with had filesystem issues because they hit other limits.  You can see some (but not all) of the limits with this command:

```
cat /proc/user_beancounters
```

#### Troubleshooting

If the `failcnt` column has a value greater than 0 or a `held` column value is equal to the corresponding `limit` value, you have hit a limit.

You can look up what each parameter is on [OpenVZ's wiki here](https://openvz.org/UBC).  A parameter may be "primary", "secondary", or "auxiliary".

You should contact your hosting provider for further assistance if you find that you cannot decrease the `held` count for a limit that your VPS has reached.

This answer can be expanded a lot depending on which beans were maxed out, as different limits being reached cause different symptoms.

### Cause: Limit(s) Decreased After Being Hit

Regarding `/proc/user_beancounters` or `df -i`, sometimes, a Virtuozzo system administrator may decrease the `limit` of a parameter below the `held` value.

For example, if the original limit of the `diskinodes` parameter was 1,500,000 and you hit the limit then someone at your hosting provider sets your inode limit to 1,000,000, you would see a bizarre inode report from `df -i` that makes no sense.

On your end, you could see an unreasonably large number, [like 18,446,744,069,620,218,961](https://superuser.com/questions/959175/disk-quota-exceeded-when-writing-to-tmp-but-plenty-of-space-linux/959221#comment1311785_959221).

I consider this to be a sinister behavior from the hosting provider, especially if they don't inform you, because the unusual values you see go against the knowledge of super users who don't have experience with Virtuozzo/OpenVZ, which leads to misleading advice ([example](https://superuser.com/a/959190/83694), [another example](https://superuser.com/questions/959175/disk-quota-exceeded-when-writing-to-tmp-but-plenty-of-space-linux/959221#comment1310322_959175)).

#### Troubleshooting

Contact your hosting provider.  Show them what you found and work with them to get your held beans below the limit.

If they refuse to help you, ditch your hosting provider and find another one that doesn't use Virtuozzo/OpenVZ virtualization.  KVM virtualization, VMware virtualization, Xen virtualization, or bare metal servers would be subject to far fewer limits than Virtuozzo/OpenVZ.

#### Explanation

Your hosting provider may have been auditing or responding to an alert and found that your VPS was using up too much of a specific resource (almost always the inodes limit, which is the `diskinodes` parameter on their end).

An inexperienced Virtuozzo admin at the hosting provider believes that they can cap the issue by reducing the limit to something lower than the actual resource usage.  In the case of inodes, you may have a lower allocation, like 1,000,000, even though your actual current usage may be higher, like 1,500,000.

The Virtuozzo admin in their control panel would see your actual usage and the new limit, but you would see bogus numbers that are possibly very unreasonably high due to the way that Virtuozzo virtualizes.

A negligent Virtuozzo admin would not inform you of this change, which is why you should contact your hosting provider if this happens to you.

Comment: i don't know if 18,446,744,069,620,218,961 is an acceptable number of inodes for a site that runs wordpress...

Comment: @BerryTsakala: Is that the number of inodes used or the total number of inodes supported by the filesystem?  If you could provide the full output of the command, we could be sure.  Based on what you wrote so far, it seems like your host doesn't have an inode limit set, which means that I would be wrong.  I'll have an updated answer for you which explores Virtuozzo limits further.

Comment: @BerryTsakala: It just occurred to me that your host may be doing something sinister and hoping you won't notice.  I will update my answer shortly with details.

Comment: thank you! i already started deleteing redundant files. I also discovered a spammer abuses the system, and email are filling up qmail's queue.

Comment: BTW, the inode doesn't sum up:  df -i is 100 trillion times larger than tje sum returned via the find... command.   Would you know how to locate  the discrepency?

Comment: Awesome, @BerryTsakala.  Thank you for letting us know what it was!  I'm glad I could help.  As explained in my answer, the bogus `df -i` count can be caused by a Virtuozzo admin lowering the value of the `diskinodes` limit.

Comment: Thanks, GoDaddy offer (at the low end) "dedicated" (virtual) servers with 512GB of disk space, but only 655,360 inodes.  Their higher end offerings go well TB territory, although whether they grant you any more inodes is another question entirely.

Comment: That is appalling, @Orwellophile!

Comment: Online Support says: "I am working with our Admins now to increase your inodes"

Comment: They increased it to 9,800,000. (15 times the previous).  Sorry if this is horrifically off topic, but they're a huge provider and the company name will assist googling.

Answer (score 5):

"Disk quota exceeded" doesn't mean that there is no space available on your disk, but that you are not allowed to use so much space.

In general, quotas are some limits set by administrator - maximum number of processes you can run, how much space you can occupy, how many files you can have, etc. Disk quotas can be set for maximum number of inodes and disk blocks.

Try running `quota` and `quota -g` (alternatively, you can run `repquota -u` and `repqouta -g`) to see if your user is restricted in this way and how. If yes, you can edit those quotas with `edquota` or turn them off with `quotaoff` command. You might need to log in as root for this, depending on your settings.

[This site](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialQuotas.html) covers a few examples how to work with quotas and also contains links to manual pages to useful commands.